# Запись показывается не полностью в меню меток

Tags: дефект, метки, дизайн

Заметил такую проблему:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

может уже знаете этот косяк, но я на всякий случай выложу вопрос.

Comment: На [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/329175/260198) и на [SOen](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385795/1991579). Второй месяц исправляют (:

Comment: понял, тогда это и не новость :)